# How to disable Evernote web view "max-width" with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css

Evernote places a `max-width` limit on web view content, and I have identified its location in Chrome developer tool(F12). Evidence: Unticking the checkbox beside "max-width" will stretch the table to full window width.

My question is, how can I remove that css statement with JavaScript code?

I have tried this:

```
document.getElementById("container").style.removeProperty("max-width")
```

but in vain.

[image: Evernote web view sample]

The above web page can be reached at http://www.evernote.com/l/ABXYD6q6bM9MyaAfRs78hQnq6VMINfVJODg/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that this statement isn't set as inline style, you won't be able to remove it.
However, you could change its value and set it to `none` by adding an inline style declaration, which will override the current value.

**Demo:**

```
var elem = document.getElementById('container');
elem.style.maxWidth = 'none';
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how webview works, but could you try using javascript to add a new class to it that added a max-width of 100%?

```
document.getElementById("container").classList.add('no-max-width');
```

then in the styles.css put

.no-max-width {
     max-width: 100%;    }

If that's not possible, then try

```
document.getElementById("container").style.maxWidth('100%');
```

Though I sometimes have trouble with .styles so not sure if that is exactly right, plus I've read it's better to add classes rather than play with css styles in JS, but also not sure how accurate that is.